Extract numeric values out of a nvarchar column in SQL
I'm trying to extract the number of gallons out of a string column in SQL. However, I'm not quite sure how to do so since the string column can contain anything. Attached is an image of what I'm dealing with. I managed to write a query that removes everything before the first numerical character (SQL below and the "Test" column in the image) however, can't figure out how to remove everything after the numerical characters in the "Test" column. There's also a scenario where there isn't a numerical value at all in the column, and a date field which I also am not concerned about.
SQL statement removing everything to the left of first numerical number:
substring([Description], PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', [Description]), LEN([Description])) as Test

The results I'm trying to get:
null
29.10
129
null
140
382
112.50
250
69.60
135.4

Example


Here's a guide on how to ask a question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Please update your post to replace your sample data (REFUEL UNIT 29.10 GALS, etc) with text or a markdown table, not an image.  Also, what version of SQL Server are you running. Execute the command SELECT @@version.

You tagged the question with t-sql but didn't tag the actual DBMS. I have assumed [sql-server], but that isn't the only DBMS that uses T-SQL. Please add the appropriate DBMS tag to your question.

As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

First, I grabbed everything before the first numerical character in this string field. Query:
substring([Description], PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', [Description]), LEN([Description])) as Test

Since the numerical values were now all on the left, I then used a charindex in a case statement to remove everything to the right after the space. I used a case statement because some columns didn't have a space so I was getting an error. Query:
,SUBSTRING(Test, 1 ,
case when  CHARINDEX(' ', Test) = 0 then LEN(Test) 
else CHARINDEX(' ', Test) -1 end) as GallonAmount



With unconstrained text, I doubt there is anything that will handle all cases. For your data, one approach is to:

Split the description up into parts using the STRING_SPLIT() function.
Use the TRY_CAST() function to test each value to determine if it is convertible to a float.
Filter out the parts that fail.
Select the first one that passes.

This logic can be wrapped up in an OUTER APPLY. Something like:
SELECT D.*, C.Result
FROM Data D
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 TRY_CAST(S.value AS FLOAT) AS Result
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(D.Description, ' ', 1) S
    WHERE TRY_CAST(S.value AS FLOAT) IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY S.ordinal
) C

The above only works for SQL Server 2022 (and later), because it uses the enable_ordinal option that was added in 2022.
For earlier versions, the order of STRING_SPLIT() results are not well defined. However, this is only an issue if there are multiple matches. An alternative to handle multiple matches (without the ordinal) is to just use the MAX() function.
SELECT D.*, C.Result
FROM Data D
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT MAX(TRY_CAST(S.value AS FLOAT)) AS Result
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(D.Description, ' ') S
) C

In both cases above, if no part can be cast to a float, the result is null.
Sample results (no usable test data was provided so I created my own):



Id
Description
Result1
Result2




1
Some 123.4 value
123.4
123.4


2
No value here
null
null


3
A paragraph number 1.2.3 is not a valid float
null
null


4
Mutiple 12.3 values 34.5junk here 23.4
12.3
23.4


5
A date 12/31/2024 is not a number
null
null



See this db<>fiddle for a demo.
If you have issues with punctuation like commas or sentence-ending-periods interfering with the numbers, you may need to pre-process the string with something like REPLACE(REPLACE(Description + ' ', ',', ' '), '. ', ' '). Note that we replace the punctuation with a space to avoid accidentally combining numbers. Also, the period is only replaced if followed by a space or at the end of the string (that's what the +' ' is for).

Thanks for the update. I wasn't able to replicate what you had shown above and I think it's because I'm still using the 2018 version of the SSMS app. However, I was able to figure out how to remove everything from the right of the SQL query I had that populated the "Test" column. I had to use a case statement just in case the column didn't have any spaces.
,SUBSTRING(Test, 1 ,
case when  CHARINDEX(' ', Test) = 0 then LEN(Test)
else CHARINDEX(' ', Test) -1 end) as GallonAmount
Again, it's not getting me to a perfect answer, but it is getting me closer to where I was before. Thanks!
